# Integrating Calendar 365 and Access 2013 data

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, calendar, ms-access-2013

I have an Access 2013 desktop database which is being used to monitor clients and appointments they have. Each client may have multiple appointments. The appointments go on a particular shared calendar with a VBA script depending on the type of appointment. We have the online Office 365 suite with sharepoint, excel, flow, dynamics, etc. Considering the relationship database and the need to populate particular calendars as well as collect various data what would be the best way to develop the system further? Currently it is only accessible by a few people on a shared drive. We'd like to expand usage with more views of data for other operations. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How about http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Create_Outlook_Appointment%2C_Shared_Folder

Comment: I have something like this. Great for what it is now but I'm looking to be able to share the system more widely while retaining some security.